# Add comment button doesn't go away on Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

When I click "add comment" on an answer on the Stack Exchange Android app, I get a comment box, but the "add comment" button doesn't go away. Instead, the "post" button comes up in another place.

Android 4.3 on [Nexus 7 (2012 version)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_%282012_version%29) with Stack Exchange Android app v. 39.

[image]

Comment: Just tried it now, confirmed that this is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 0.1.40 coming out later today the visibility of the "Add Comment" is directly inverse to the visibility of the comment container on the bottom of the page, thanks!